# SQL not working - keeps refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, sql

This SQL is meant to run once people change submit the 'change password' page. They will have filled out 'newpw' and 'confirmpw' and submitted the page.
The SQL is meant to then check if newpw == confirmpw, and if it matches, it''' update the password in the logins table, and redirect them back to their player profile. If they don't match, it'll bring them right back to change-password.

My issue is that, even with them matching, it keeps bringing me back to change-password.php, even more annoyingly, the second time around, it appears to drop the 'pid' of the player.

Everything looks right to me, so I guess I need some fresh eyes... Any ideas what the issue is?

```
                        // Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
                    if ($_POST['test'])
                    {
                        if ($_POST["newpw"] == $_POST["confirmpw"]) {
                            $pid = $_SESSION["pid"];
                            $new = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirmpw']);
                            $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE logins SET password='$new' WHERE username='$player'");
                            $confirmation = "Thank You; your password has now been changed.";
                        echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                            window.alert('$confirmation')
                            window.location.href='playerparent-profile.php?pid=$pid';
                            </SCRIPT>";
                            exit();
                        } else {
                                header("location: change-password.php?pid=$pid"); 
                        }
                    }
                        ?>
```

**html**

```
                 <form action="change-password.php?pid=<?=$pid?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
                  <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20726"><!-- group -->
                   <div class="grpelem" id="u20726"><!-- simple frame --></div>
                   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20724"><!-- group -->
                    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20725-4"><!-- content -->
                     <p>CHANGE PASSWORD</p>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20727-4"><!-- group -->
                   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20727-4"><!-- content -->
                    <p>OLD PASSWORD:</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="grpelem"><input type="text" required id="u20729" name="oldpw" title="Fill in your old password. This field is required" class="form-element form-element-medium text-element"  /><!-- simple frame --></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20728-4"><!-- group -->
                   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20728-4"><!-- content -->
                    <p>NEW PASSWORD:</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="grpelem" ><input type="password" required id="u20730" name="newpw" title="Fill in your old password. This field is required" class="form-element form-element-medium text-element"  /><!-- simple frame --></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20733-4"><!-- group -->
                   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20733-4"><!-- content -->
                    <p>CONFIRM NEW PASSWORD:</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="grpelem"><input type="password" required id="u20735" name="confirmpw" title="Fill in your old password. This field is required" class="form-element form-element-medium text-element"  /><!-- simple frame --></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="colelem" id="u20737"><!-- simple frame --></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20738"><!-- group -->
                  <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20739-4"><!-- content -->
                    <p><a href="#" name="test" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Change Password</a> <?=$pid?><p>
                 </form>
```

Comment: i think you don't have field "test" to get the value $_POST['test']

Comment: unrelated, but you should salt and hash your passwords before storing them.

Comment: @Chandu well, I take back what I said. You were correct! I created a hidden field and gave test a value of 1, now everything works! If you could actually submit that as an answer so I can vote it, that'd be great :)

Comment: sure i would put it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you don't have field "test" to get the value $_POST['test']

Answer (score 0):

Try to `var_dump` your `$_POST` and check the array structure, because you're accessing some 'test' field that doesn't exists. This is the `<a>` `name` property and will give you no values when posting, since it's just performing submit action via JS.

Comment: Which POST should I be dumping?

Comment: The superglobal only one: var_dump($_POST). Check the output for structural debug of the variable.